# Roman environment influences the rest of the equation

Tags: math-mode, fonts

When I use the `\rm{}` command inside an equation, some of the things outside the `{}` are printed wrongly.

For instance, in

```
$\rm{Norm}_{L/\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_p)}(x)$
```

the `x` is not printed as it should be, namely, math italics.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\rm` is a switch, i.e., it does *not* take an argument. Writing `\rm{uvw} abc` is therefore equivalent to writing `\rm uvw abc`. That's why you're getting the outcome you observe. You should be writing `{\rm Norm}...`. Incidentally, if you use LaTeX (your write-up isn't clear about whether you use plainTeX or LaTeX), you shouldn't be using `\rm` at all. Instead, you should be using (in a math context) `\mathrm`. `\mathrm` does take an argument, by the way; hence, writing `\mathrm{Norm}` will behave exactly as you'd expect it to.

Comment: It seems to me that `Norm` is a function, then it might be better to actually define it as such (if using `amsmath`: `\DeclareMathOperator\Norm{Norm}` and then just use `\Norm`. That is a lot cleaner than using `\mathrm{Norm}` all over. Additionally, now `2\Norm(x)` looks better, `2\mathrm{Norm}` looks wrong.

Comment: @Mico The code has `\mathbf`, so definitely LaTeX.

Comment: @EmmanuelLecouturier The `\rm` command has been deprecated in LaTeX for 25 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(restating my comment as an answer, so that this query may be considered to have received at least one answer)

`\rm` is a switch, i.e., it does *not* take an argument. Writing `\rm{uvw} abc` is therefore equivalent to writing `\rm uvw abc`. Observe that `\rm` applies not only to "uvw" but, crucially, to the subsequent "abc" as well. You should really be writing `{\rm Norm}`.

Incidentally, since you use LaTeX (the `\mathbf` directive is a bit of a give-away...), you shouldn't be using `\rm` at all. `\rm` is plain-TeX syntax, which is not even defined in the LaTeX kernel. Some LaTeX document classes still support `\rm` (and `\bf`, `\it`, `\sf`, `\tt`, etc.), but others do not. If you care about long-term robustness of your code and about portability across document classes, you should definitely not use `\rm` any more. In a math context, you should be using `\mathrm` instead. `\mathrm` does take an argument; hence, writing `\mathrm{Norm}` will behave exactly as you'd expect it to.

An additional comment: If "Norm" is an "operator" -- as in "Norm(u)" -- writing `\mathrm{Norm}` is sub-optimal. Do load the `amsmath` package (you may already be doing so...), issue the directive

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Norm}{Norm}
```

in the preamble, and write `\Norm{u}` in the body of the document. Assigning the status "math operator" to `\Norm` comes some pretty substantial typographic benefits.